# How to force kill a thread when a class instance goes out of scope?

Tags: python, multithreading, asynchronous, serial-port

A little background, I am working on implementing a library for serial communication for HCI. There are two packets of concern Sync and Async.  The sync is very easy as it is call and response, but the async is tricky because it can come at anytime. The initial design uses a thread to constantly read the serial port and build packets, which then get pushed into a queue. The software then pops these packets off and goes about its business. The thread comes with the class instantiation as to be opaque and overall the approach works well.

A **del** method is implemented and will kill the thread at the end of the program. However, if the instance goes out of scope and another instance is created the thread is never killed and a new thread is created.

I have  tried **del**, but it is unreliable.
I have considered a singleton pattern, but prefer to not use it if possible.

Is there anyway to guarantee the destruction of the thread, or is there some better design pattern I should be using?

```
from  threading import Thread

class ThreadedClass:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        
        self._kill_thread = False
        self._read_thread = Thread(
            target=self._read_process , daemon=True
        )
        self._read_thread.start()

    def _read_process(self):
        print('THREAD START')
        while not self._kill_thread:
            #do work
            pass
    def __del__(self):
        self._kill_thread = True
        self._read_thread.join()
        print('Thread killed')

    def foo(self):
        print(self._kill_thread)



def scope():
    t = ThreadedClass()
    t.foo()

scope()
scope()
```

Output

```
THREAD START
False
THREAD START
False
```

Note the thread is never being killed.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mre] of this issue, and include any code relevant to your attempt to solve the problem. Remember, we can't help you if we can't see what you're doing!